# unable to setup net.tcp bindings for wcf application running on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, wcf-binding, iis-8, net.tcp

I am trying to set up `NET.TCP` bindings for a `WCF` application deployed on `IIS`. I have already added net.tcp to `Enabled Protocols` of application, but when I am trying to add net.tcp binding, its throwing the error shown below:

[image]

I have also activated the `Windows Communication Foundation Non-HTTP Activation`. NET.TCP services are also running.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to add net.tcp to the enabled protocols of your site. Go to IIS Manager, right-click on your website, go to 'Manage Web Site' or 'Manage Application', then to 'Advanced Settings...'. There you see 'Enabled Protocols'. It probably says http. Change it to http,net.tcp

OR

use command line - it works for me

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" -+bindings.[protocol='net.tcp',bindinginformation='808:*']
```

Answer (score 1):

read these 2 and see if they have anything extra than what you are doing right now, so see what you are missing and do that:

http://dotnetmentors.com/hosting-wcf-service-with-nettcpbinding-or-netnamedpipebinding-in-iis.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/james_osbornes_blog/archive/2010/12/07/hosting-in-iis-using-nettcpbinding.aspx

if these 2 didn't help, than can read this, covers few more points than other 2 links:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prathul/archive/2011/11/28/hosting-wcf-nettcp-on-iis-was.aspx