# Configuring net.tcp Binding in IIS 8

Tags: wcf-binding, iis-8

I'm trying to enable **netTcpBinding** in IIS 8. I have both **Net.Tcp Listener-Adapter**- and **Net.TCP Sharing**-services installed and running. When I'm trying to add the net.tcp connection type in Add Binding-Dialog, this happens:

[image]

The error basically tells that some object is null. I've tried with all possible Binding information strings, typically the docs tell to use `"808:*"`. The field cannot be left empty, there must be something otherwise the OK button is disabled. Any binding string, including gibberish like "jghfj" result in the same error.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: I had the same issue and this answer helped me http://stackoverflow.com/a/40721957/105445